# Are there 6 zeno alive?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super, if I recall correctly, it was told that each ring of time represents an alternative timeline/reality. It was shown by Gowasu there were 6 rings of time, one of them which exploded when Zeno destroyed one timeline

[image]

. Since there is a "present Zeno" and a "future Zeno" of 2 different timelines, are there supposed to be another 4 Zenos due to the other timelines/realities which were created by Trunks and Zamasu time travels?

Comment: Yeah there should be, one Zeno for each timeline that is create.

Comment: It was never shown in the series, but since each timeline creates a new Zeno there should be 6 Zenos alive.